# java.sql.SQLException: null, message from server: "Host 'xxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I am currently trying to access mySQL-database through a Java Application.
In order to do so, I downloaded the "mysql-connector-java-5.1.42-bin.jar" file and imported it to Eclipse Neon.3.
My MySQL Server is up and running as following screenshot Shows:
[image]

I have tried it with following code:

```
final private String user = "root";
final private String passwd = "root";

public void connectToDB() throws Exception {
  try {
    // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String url= "jdbc:mysql://xxx:3306/pilotproject";                

    // Setup the connection with the DB
    connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
    System.out.println("Database connection established"); 
  {
{
```

but I am getting following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host 'xxx.fuchs.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1040)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2194)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2225)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2024)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:779)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at MySQLAccess.connectToDB(MySQLAccess.java:29)
at PilotFrame1$1.run(PilotFrame1.java:44)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any suggestions on how I can solve this Problem?
I appreciate every help or advice you can give me, thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql

Comment: I have already tried that but there is no bind-address entry in my my-default.ini. (I am using MySQL Server 5.7 btw)

Answer (score 2):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

this helped!